# How to get all pipes from api pipefy?

Tags: taskmanager

I find [api](https://pipefypipe.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/list-pipes), but I don't understand. How to get list pipes. Without ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the organizations object and get all the pipes of the organization.

Example:

```
{
  organization(id: 123) {
    pipes {
      id
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!